# Passing multiple parameters on Svelte action

Tags: javascript, svelte

Accordingly to the Svelte documentation:

> Actions are functions that are called when an element is created. They can return an object with a destroy method that is called after the element is unmounted

I want to pass multiple parameters to a Svelte action function, but only the last one is recogonized

[**DEMO**](https://svelte.dev/repl/121e4b24ec3c4bbdb67122fcf9364ef3?version=3.15.0)

```
<script>
    function example(node, arg1, arg2) {
        // the node has been mounted in the DOM
        console.log(arg1, arg2) // Should display 'a b', but actually only displays 'b undefined'
        return {
            destroy() {
                // the node has been removed from the DOM
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<h1 use:example={'a', 'b'}>Hello World!</div>
```

Is there any viable solution that avoid the use of a single object as parameter?

```
<script>
    function example(node, arg) {
        // the node has been mounted in the DOM
        console.log(arg) // Returns a object with the arguments
        return {
            destroy() {
                // the node has been removed from the DOM
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<h1 use:example>Hello World!</div>

<!-- Passing parameters -->
<h1 use:example={{
    arg1: [50, 75, 100],
    arg2: true
}}>Works like a charm!</h1>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The content between `{}` can be any JavaScript expression, and when you write `'a', 'b'` you are using the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), so the value of the entire expression will be `'b'`.

You could use an array instead.

**Example ([REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/a9115066c87b4b7ea2e83e9c54c1a5cf?version=3.15.0))**

```html
<script>
  function example(node, [arg1, arg2]) {
    console.log(arg1, arg2)
    return {
      destroy() {
        // the node has been removed from the DOM
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<h1 use:example="{['a', 'b']}">Hello World!</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

You also can use an array.

Below a snippet of my code:

```
export function initMapDesc(mapMark) {

  // make the entry (obj) and the composed search regex reactive
  return (node, [obj, pRex]) => {
    // the node has been mounted in the DOM
    node.innerHTML = mapObj(node, obj, pRex, mapMark);

    return {
      update([obj, pRex]) {
        node.innerHTML = mapObj(node, obj, pRex, mapMark);
      },
      // destroy the node to clear the view (on session change)
      destroy() {
        node.innerHTML = '';
      }
    };
  };
};
```

This code renders an object into a table `<td>` node. The regex stream is used to search nodes and mark the search results.

The code below shows the call of the use function. A closure is used to pass an object to the use function and to receive the regex search results.

```
const mapMark = {         // mapMark Obj
  markedIds: [],          // marked result row ids 
  skipProps: ['kind', 'method', 'type', 'bic']
};
const mapper = initMapDesc(mapMark);
```

and in the HTML:

```
<td id="{key}" class="space-normal" use:mapper={[$norm.map[key], $pseudoRex]}></td>
```

I have submitted a [proposal](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/3935) to allow object and class methods to be used in a use directive.